# extjs: combobox typeahead does not work with querymode : remote

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have an extjs combobox whose `queryMode` is set to `remote`.
I also want the `typeAhead` feature in it. But typeahead doenst work in this case.
The store reloads to the original data even after typing some text in the combobox.

Here is my code:

```
var queryStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
//autoLoad: true,
model: 'UserQuery',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'queryBuilder_getQueryList',
    extraParams: {
        tableId: this.title
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
},
listeners: {
    load: function () {
        var combo = Ext.getCmp('cmbQueryList');
        var lst = this.last();
        if (lst)combo.setValue(lst.data);
    }
}

});


var queryCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    width: 200,
    id: 'cmbQueryList',
    store: queryStore,
    valueField: 'queryID',
    displayField: 'queryName',
    typeAhead: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    emptyText: 'Select Query...',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    triggerAction: 'query',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    editable: true
 });
```

Please suggest how do I get typeAhead and querymode remote to work together.

Comment: Hi DarkKnightFan, were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this code corking for me .I guess your store property autoload is true so when you going to select the combobox its going to server and reload the data. please remove the property of store auto load true. Then its working.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({  

    fieldLabel:'Apps',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    typeAhead: true,
    listWidth : 345,
    store: myStore(),
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode:'remote',
    maxLength: 50,
    editable: false,
    anchor : '90%',
    selectOnFocus:true

 }),
```

Comment: I set the autoLoad property of store to false. Still no change. Everytime I enter text in the combobox, the store gets reloaded and the combobox gets reset (text entered by gets cleared)

Comment: added my store in the original question